# How is form_for setting the action of the html form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following the rails guides' tutorial, I ran into an issue where I learnt about plural vs. singular naming and repercussions. Now that I know this going forward, I'm interested in learning if it's possible to work around this -- without having to rename my controller.

I've passed a new :url_path to form_for (account_path) and my 'rake routes' outputs an entry:

```
account GET    /account/:id(.:format)      account#show
```

I still get the following error when trying to access the page with the form:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"account"}
```

My routes.rb has an entry for the plural resources directory (resources :account)... Understanding that the singular version works, but the controller still represents "many".

Any insight for a green RoR dev?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a typo - you should write `resource :account`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not much actually, as mentioned in the original question, I know that the singular version works, but isn't that changing the definition of my controller? Since it's a controller that represents many. (I lose the match for /account/show/:id)